Spontaneous polarization of WSe2 using VASP
I am trying to use VASP to calculate spontaneous electric polarization in WSe₂ (semiconductor) with the following INCAR settings:
SYSTEM = WSe2
EDIFF = 1E-6
PREC = Accurate
ISMEAR = 0
LCALCPOL = .TRUE.
DIPOL = 0.5 0.5 0.5
LDIPOL = .TRUE.
NELM = 200

POSCAR here is already optimized with PBE. But when I add LCALPOL, DIPOL, and LDIPOL to INCAR as above, the electronic SC no longer converges and I need some hints to proceed. Is there any obvious mistake in my settings that causes my calculation to not converge?
I noticed that certain parameters like DIPOL and EFIELD_PEAD might affect the results. My main goal is to accurately capture the polarization effects in the z-direction, and I'm unsure if the inclusion of a small electric field is necessary for this specific calculation.
Given that WSe₂ is a layered material, are there any recommended practices or common pitfalls to avoid during these calculations?
My INCAR used to optimize POSCAR looks like ...
ALGO = Fast
EDIFF = 1E-4
ENCUT = 520
IBRION = 2
ISIF = 3
ISMEAR = -5
ISPIN = 2
LASPH = True
LMAXMIX = 6
LORBIT = 11
LREAL = Auto
LWAVE = False
MAGMOM = 2*5.0 4*0.6
NELM = 100
NSW = 99
PREC = Accurate
SIGMA = 0.05

which optimized my POSCAR to ...
W2 Se4
   1.00000000000000
     1.6645343355557378   -2.8830580401254404    0.0000000000000000
     1.6645343355557378    2.8830580401254404    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   13.8375857837622789
   W    Se
     2     4
Direct
  0.6666666666666643  0.3333333333333357  0.7500000000000000
  0.3333333333333357  0.6666666666666643  0.2500000000000000
  0.3333333333333357  0.6666666666666643  0.8713483622013694
  0.6666666666666643  0.3333333333333357  0.3713483622013622
  0.3333333333333357  0.6666666666666643  0.6286516377986306
  0.6666666666666643  0.3333333333333357  0.1286516377986307

Thank you for your assistance!

I would need to know the contents of your OUTCAR and OSZICAR as well as the VASP version you are using. Versions of VASP <6.3.1 have a bug related to dipole moments in non-orthogonal unit cells. I would suggest setting IDIPOL or checking density mixing parameters - sometimes charge sloshing could cause an error like this.

@BactrianFan Thanks for your comment. It turned out that setting IDIPOL = 3 brought the convergence back. I'm using VASP 6.3.2 so the bug shouldn't be the issue. If you can write your comment as a full answer, I'll select it as the answer.

Hi 태현 , I am glad it helped. Unfortunately, my answer was converted to a comment. So I believe it is up to the moderators to consider it an answer haha. Best of luck with everything!
